# Remmina RDP windows disappear permanently once minimized

Tags: bug-reporting, remmina

Even with the latest updates, when using the Remmina client to connect over an RDP session, if I minimize the window, the icon in the Unity Taskbar *closes* (looks like the program isn't running) but remmina is still a running process.  I have not found a way to bring the window back (the alt+tab list does not include it).

I see [a bug report on Ubuntu Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/782331) for it which mentions a fix (9 months ago), but I have all the updates.  The resolution there claims it's no longer an issue in Ubuntu 11.  Also, the project pages on SourceForge and GitHub -- I can't tell which of these is supposed to be current/authoritative!?  Neither mentions the reappearance of this bug, but there's no a lot of activity otherwise.

Am I alone with this problem?

Since I'm new to Linux-world, how am I supposed to know where to report the bug, since there are at least three plausibly-authoritative websites?

How can I work-around or patch this minimize bug?

Thanks!

Comment: One work-around is to hit Super-key+W. This brings up all of your windows. Super key is what the Linux community calls the Windows key, if you didn't know.

Comment: @Tinellus: It's not working in my case. I have to stop it by kill process and start it once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could try is in 'edit' 'preferences' 'applet' tab, uncomment the 'disable tray icon'. You should now get the icon in your panel, which you can click to unminimize.
Hope this helps

Comment: @MahendraKorat - this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by unchecking, in edit -> preferences -> applet, the checkbox "Minimize windows to tray"

Answer (score 1):

For me works

```
gedit /home/user/.remmina/remmina.pref
```

change

```
disable_tray_icon=true
```

to

```
disable_tray_icon=false
```